# How to solve x'A=b' instead of Ax=b?

Tags: r, function, inverse

I solve Ax=b by using

```
solve(A, b)
```

which is faster than

```
solve(A) %*% b
```

Then, how do i solve (' is a transpose)

```
x'A=b'?
```

I don't like to use

```
b' %*% solve(A)
```

since this is slow.
Is there any way I can solve by just one solve() function?

Answer (score 4):

```
x' A = b'
```

is the same as:

```
A' x = b
```

So you can basically use `solve(t(A), b)` and take the result's transpose to get `x'`.

Comment: This is brilliant!